# Optimizing the process of finding word association strengths from an input text

Tags: python, performance, loops, nlp, analytics

I have written the following (crude) code to find the association strengths among the words in a given piece of text.

```
import re

## The first paragraph of Wikipedia's article on itself - you can try with other pieces of text with preferably more words (to produce more meaningful word pairs)
text = "Wikipedia was launched on January 15, 2001, by Jimmy Wales and Larry Sanger.[10] Sanger coined its name,[11][12] as a portmanteau of wiki[notes 3] and 'encyclopedia'. Initially an English-language encyclopedia, versions in other languages were quickly developed. With 5,748,461 articles,[notes 4] the English Wikipedia is the largest of the more than 290 Wikipedia encyclopedias. Overall, Wikipedia comprises more than 40 million articles in 301 different languages[14] and by February 2014 it had reached 18 billion page views and nearly 500 million unique visitors per month.[15] In 2005, Nature published a peer review comparing 42 science articles from Encyclopadia Britannica and Wikipedia and found that Wikipedia's level of accuracy approached that of Britannica.[16] Time magazine stated that the open-door policy of allowing anyone to edit had made Wikipedia the biggest and possibly the best encyclopedia in the world and it was testament to the vision of Jimmy Wales.[17] Wikipedia has been criticized for exhibiting systemic bias, for presenting a mixture of 'truths, half truths, and some falsehoods',[18] and for being subject to manipulation and spin in controversial topics.[19] In 2017, Facebook announced that it would help readers detect fake news by suitable links to Wikipedia articles. YouTube announced a similar plan in 2018."
text = re.sub("[\[].*?[\]]", "", text)     ## Remove brackets and anything inside it.
text=re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9.]+", ' ', text)  ## Remove special characters except spaces and dots
text=str(text).lower()                     ## Convert everything to lowercase
## Can add other preprocessing steps, depending on the input text, if needed.







from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk

stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

desirable_tags = ['NN'] # We want only nouns - can also add 'NNP', 'NNS', 'NNPS' if needed, depending on the results

word_list = []

for sent in text.split('.'):
    for word in sent.split():
        '''
        Extract the unique, non-stopword nouns only
        '''
        if word not in word_list and word not in stop_words and nltk.pos_tag([word])[0][1] in desirable_tags:
            word_list.append(word)





'''
Construct the association matrix, where we count 2 words as being associated 
if they appear in the same sentence.

Later, I'm going to define associations more properly by introducing a 
window size (say, if 2 words seperated by at most 5 words in a sentence, 
then we consider them to be associated)
'''

table = np.zeros((len(word_list),len(word_list)), dtype=int)

for sent in text.split('.'):
    for i in range(len(word_list)):
        for j in range(len(word_list)):
            if word_list[i] in sent and word_list[j] in sent:
                table[i,j]+=1

df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=word_list, index=word_list)







# Count the number of occurrences of each word from word_list in the text

all_words = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(df), 2)), columns=['Word', 'Count'])
all_words.Word = df.index

for sent in text.split('.'):
    count=0
    for word in sent.split():
        if word in word_list:
            all_words.loc[all_words.Word==word,'Count'] += 1







# Sort the word pairs in decreasing order of their association strengths

df.values[np.triu_indices_from(df, 0)] = 0 # Make the upper triangle values 0

assoc_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Word 1', 'Word 2', 'Association Strength (Word 1 -> Word 2)'])
for row_word in df:
    for col_word in df:
        '''
        If Word1 occurs 10 times in the text, and Word1 & Word2 occur in the same sentence 3 times,
        the association strength of Word1 and Word2 is 3/10 - Please correct me if this is wrong.
        '''
        assoc_df = assoc_df.append({'Word 1': row_word, 'Word 2': col_word, 
                                        'Association Strength (Word 1 -> Word 2)': df[row_word][col_word]/all_words[all_words.Word==row_word]['Count'].values[0]}, ignore_index=True)

assoc_df.sort_values(by='Association Strength (Word 1 -> Word 2)', ascending=False)
```

This produces the word associations like so:

```
        Word 1          Word 2          Association Strength (Word 1 -> Word 2)
330     wiki            encyclopedia    3.0
895     encyclopadia    found           1.0
1317    anyone          edit            1.0
754     peer            science         1.0
755     peer            encyclopadia    1.0
756     peer            britannica      1.0
...
...
...
```

However, the code contains a lot of `for` loops which hampers its running time. Specially the last part (`sort the word pairs in decreasing order of their association strengths`) consumes a lot of time as it computes the association strengths of `n^2` word pairs/combinations, where `n` is the number of words we are interested in (those in `word_list` in my code above).

So, the following are what I would like some help on:

1. How do I vectorize the code, or otherwise make it more efficient?
2. Instead of producing `n^2` combinations/pairs of words in the last step, is there any way to prune some of them before producing them? I am going to prune some of the useless/meaningless pairs by inspection after they are produced anyway.
3. Also, and I know this does not fall into the purview of a coding question, but I would love to know if there's any mistake in my logic, specially when calculating the word association strengths.

Comment: Are you set on writing your own word embedding library as part of a learning exercise? Because if not, you should check out some of the pre-existing libraries for working with word vectors such as [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) or [magnitude](https://github.com/plasticityai/magnitude). These are well-tested, and are based on highly optimized C code that will run orders of magnitude faster than anything you'll write in pure Python.

Comment: @J.Taylor `gensim` and `magnitude` are for word embeddings, and consequently, semantic word-similarity computations, no? I don't need to use my own code, but I didn't find any existing python library that computes association strengths among the words in a given text. That's why I had to write my own.

Comment: Word embeddings are for exactly that - computing associations between words based upon the context they are found in within the corpus of texts they are trained on. Also, on the same note as before, unless you want to write your own tokenizer for educational purposes (and there is nothing wrong with that if you do), you will likely want to use `nltk.sentence_tokenizer()` instead.

Comment: Just as one example, you are splitting sentences on periods. That will split all of the following sentences incorrectly: `There will be a 4.3 degree rise in temperatures.`  ... `Where are you going? I want to eat some food! Let's go home.` ... `I was thinking ... what if we went to the movies!`. Using a well-tested, prebuilt sentence tokenizer will catch all of these weird cases you didn't think of, and will be very efficient (for python code). But again, if you're doing this because you want to learn about how to do it, that's great, and I'm not trying to discourage you from doing so!

Comment: @J.Taylor Yes, true, I should use `nltk.sentence_tokenizer` instead of splitting on periods. About computing associations between words based upon the context they are found in a corpus, that's not exactly what I am looking for. I define associations non-semantically - 2 words are associated if they simply appear in the same sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked about your specific code, I will not go into alternate libraries. I will be mostly concentrating on points 1) and 2) of your question:

Instead of iterating through the whole word ist twice (`i` and `j`) you can already cut the processing time by ~ half by just iterating `j` between `i + i` and the end of the list. This removes duplicate pairs (index 24 and 42 as well as index 42 and 24) as well as the identical pair (index 42 and 42).

```
for sent in text.split('.'):
    for i in range(len(word_list)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(word_list)):
            if word_list[i] in sent and word_list[j] in sent:
                table[i,j]+=1
```

Be careful with this, though. the `in` operator will also match partial words (like `and` in `hand`)
Of course, you could also remove the `j` iteration completely by first filtering for all words in your word list and then pairing them afterward:

```
word_list = set()    # Using set instead of list makes lookups faster since this is a hashed structure

for sent in text.split('.'):
    for word in sent.split():
        '''
        Extract the unique, non-stopword nouns only
        '''
        if word not in word_list and word not in stop_words and nltk.pos_tag([word])[0][1] in desirable_tags:
            word_list.add(word)

(...)
for sent in text.split('.'):
    found_words = [word for word in sent.split() if word in word_list]    # list comprehensions are usually faster than pure for loops
    # If you want to count duplicate words, then leave the whole line below out.
    found_words = tuple(frozenset(found_words)) #  make every word unique using a set and then iterable by index again by converting it into a tuple. 
    for i in range(len(found_words):
        for j in range(i+1, len(found_words):
            table[i, j] += 1
```

In general, you should really think about using external libraries for most of this, though. As some of the comments on your question already pointed out, splitting on `.` may get you wrong results, the same counts for splitting on whitespace, for example with words that are separated with a `-` or words that are followed by a `,`.

Comment: I'll definitely try these suggestions out. Also, I would love to know if there are alternate libraries that do this. The reason I wrote my own code is that I searched for existing libraries, but I couldn't find any existing python library that computes association strengths among the words in a given text. If you know of any, please do let me know.

Comment: I did not concentrate on alternate libraries since I do not do any language processing right now (I did in my university times, but we concentrated on doing things manually back then). I think you got a few suggestions in your comment, though that sounded promising.

Would chapter 3.6 in the linked script maybe help you with your issues as well?
http://lintool.github.io/UMD-courses/CMSC723-2009-Fall/readings/crossroads.pdf

Comment: No, it wouldn't help in my case, because of the difference in how word associations are defined. In this link, associations are defined semantically - i.e., `bread` might be associated with `knife`, `butter`, etc - words which may not even be present in the input text corpus. In my case, I want words that essentially appear close together in the input text's sentences - its not based on the meanings of the words.

Comment: Then my other suggestion (naive bayes implementations) would not help you as well. I am afraid I do not know any other helpful libraries for you then. Sorry. If no one else writes an answer with them and the comments show a few helpful libraries, I will be happy to add a list of them to the answer for completeness, helping users finding the question later, though :-)